# React state has changed but the component's props using the state has not changed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-props

I have a problem related to AfterVoteProgress component. After I import the Pool and vote for an Option, i render the afterVoteProgress that it's a progress bar and some text.

I've encoutered a problem when the pool's options are all at 0 and suddenly it sets to 1, the progress bar does not show me the correct parcentage. The state is updated but the **maxParcentage prop is not**.

How the data is parsed:

```
0: {id: 44, question_text: 'Here', votes: 0, maxParcentage: 0}
1: {id: 45, question_text: 'There', votes: 0, maxParcentage: 0}
2: {id: 46, question_text: 'Nowhere', votes: 0, maxParcentage: 0}
```

optionSelect.jsx

```
import BeforeVoteOption from './beforeVoteOption';
import AfterVoteProgress from './afterVoteProgress';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

async function getPoolData(id) {
    return fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/pools/' + id + '/?format=json', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((pools) => {
        const updatedOptions = pools.questions.map((option) => ({
          ...option,
          maxParcentage: 0,
        }));
        return { ...pools, questions: updatedOptions };
      });
  }

export default function OptionSelect({question, options}) {
    // Router
    const router = useRouter()

    const { slug } = router.query
    
    // Global States
    const [option, setOption] = useState([])
    const [voteChoice, setVoteChoice] = useState(0)
    const [hasVoted, setHasVoted] = useState(false)
    const [totalVotes, setTotalVotes] = useState(0)

    // Vote select function
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPoolData = async () => {
          if (options) {
            const value = await getPoolData(slug);
            setOption(value.questions);
          }
        };
        fetchPoolData();
    }, [options, slug]);
      

    // Before vote handlers
    const onVoteOptionChange = e => {
        setVoteChoice(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleVoteForm = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (!voteChoice == 0) {
            const endpoint = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/questions/'+ voteChoice +'/addVote/'
     
            const formUpload = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
            }
            
            const response = await fetch(endpoint, formUpload)
            const data = await response.json();

            if (data.status === 'added') {
                getPoolData(slug).then((value) => setOption(value.questions));
                setHasVoted(true);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Set Total Votes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (option) {
            console.log(option)
            setTotalVotes(0);
            option.map((data) => {
                setTotalVotes((prevVotes) => prevVotes + data.votes)
            })
        }
    }, [option])

    // After Vote Handlers

    useEffect(() => {
        if (totalVotes > 0) {
            option.map(data => {
                //console.log(data.votes)
                //console.log(totalVotes)
                const part = data.votes / totalVotes * 100
                //console.log(part)
                data.maxParcentage = part;
                //console.log(data)
                //console.log('-----------------')
            })
        }
    }, [totalVotes])

    //<AfterVoteProgress key={index} maxParcentage={data.maxParcentage} voteChoice={voteChoice} votes={data.votes} optionText={data.question_text}/>
        
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleVoteForm} className='flex flex-col box-shadow rounded-3xl p-6 gap-2'>
            <span className='font-semibold text-xl pb-1'>{question}</span>

            {!hasVoted && option.map((data, index) => (<BeforeVoteOption key={index} index={index} id={data.id} optionText={data.question_text} onVoteOptionChange={onVoteOptionChange}/>))}
            
            {hasVoted && option.map((data, index) => (console.log('showing'), <AfterVoteProgress key={index} maxParcentage={data.maxParcentage !== undefined ? data.maxParcentage : 0} voteChoice={voteChoice} votes={data.votes} optionText={data.question_text}/>))}
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
                <div className='flex flex-row items-center gap-1 '>
                    <Image src='/totalVotes.svg' width={41} height={22} /> 
                    <span className='text-sm opacity-75'>Total votes: {totalVotes}</span>
                </div>
                <button className='action-button px-4 py-2 font-semibold' type='submit'>Vote</button>
            </div>            
        </form>
    )
}
```

afterVoteProgress.jsx

```
import LinearProgress, { linearProgressClasses } from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { animate, motion } from "framer-motion";

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const BorderLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)(({ theme }) => ({
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 5,
    [`&.${linearProgressClasses.colorPrimary}`]: {
      backgroundColor: '#DBDBFF',
    },
    [`& .${linearProgressClasses.bar}`]: {
      borderRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#5E5BFF' : '#5E5BFF',
    },
  }));

export default function AfterVoteProgress({optionText, votes, maxParcentage}) {
    console.log('max parcentage ', maxParcentage)
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setProgress((prevProgress) => (prevProgress >= maxParcentage ? maxParcentage : prevProgress + 5));
        }, 100);
        
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, []);

    return( 
        <motion.div className='flex flex-col'>
            <motion.span animate={{x:0, y:0}} initial={{x:10, y:10}} className=' text-base font-medium'>{optionText}</motion.span>
            <motion.div animate={{opacity:1, x:0}} transition={{delay:0.2}} initial={{opacity:0, x:-50}}>
                <BorderLinearProgress variant='determinate' value={progress} />
            </motion.div>
            <motion.span animate={{opacity:1, y:0}} transition={{delay:1.2}} initial={{opacity:0, y:-12}} className='text-xs opacity-70'>{votes} votes</motion.span>
        </motion.div>
    )
}
```

I've tried to update the component later, but the prop is still not updated, while the state already has been changed.

**EDIT:** Looks like the problem might be in the afterVoteProgress.jsx, the data is parsed corectly but the progress bar is "late"
[image: data]

After setting the hasVoted to True, i've saw that the useEffect inside afterVoteProgress.jsx only triggers the interval after I save and "Fast refresh" the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, `data.maxParcentage = part` is wrong.

This is an anti-pattern in React, because it does not trigger a re-render of the component, and the prop is still using the old value.

To fix this, you need to update state immutably using `setOption` function.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (totalVotes > 0) {
    const updatedOptions = option.map((data) => {
      const part = (data.votes / totalVotes) * 100;
      return { ...data, maxParcentage: part };
    });
    setOption(updatedOptions);
  }
}, [totalVotes]);
```

Comment: I've found out that the problem might be in the AfterVoteProgress part, if the option had 0 votes before and now it has 1, the progress bar does not show up, it only shows if the option has more than 1 votes, then it starts to spread correctly, like it's a step behind or something

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is related to updating the maxParcentage prop in the option array. In React, changing the value of a property in an object within an array doesn't trigger a re-render of the component. Therefore, even though you update the maxParcentage value in the state, it doesn't reflect in the rendered component. Try using the below method:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (totalVotes > 0) {
    const updatedOptions = option.map(data => ({
      ...data,
      maxParcentage: (data.votes / totalVotes) * 100
    }));

    setOption(updatedOptions);
  }
}, [totalVotes]);
```